# Is this zip function ok?

Tags: scheme, racket

A slick way to write the zip function in Scheme/Racket:

```
(define (zip . lsts)
  (apply map list lsts))

(zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
'((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

Is using cons instead of list in zip to get a list of dotted-pairs correct?

```
(define (zip-dot . lsts)
  (apply map cons lsts))

(zip-dot '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
'((1 . a) (2 . b) (3 . c))
```

Comment: Not really. See `(zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3) '("BABY" "YOU" "ME"))` for the reason. The dot notation is generally reserved for functions of arbitrary arity.  `cons` can only be called with 2 arguments. While it works if applied to two lists, it fails in other cases, which is not what you expect when you see the function argument dot notation.

Comment: Are you mixing dotted pairs with dot notation for arbitrary arity of functions?

Comment: No, zip-dot works if you pass it two arguments, but if you pass in the wrong number of arguments, `cons` will throw an error, and if in a non-trivial codebase, you'll weep, and bash your head against the desk trying to figure out which F^$*%$@ `cons` is misbehaving. whereas if you get an error back from `zip-dot` you'll have a narrower search window. Thus the reason the arbitary arity notation should only be used where you can actually accept a arbitrary number of arguments.